# Regression with analytic weight in python

Tags: python, regression, stata, statsmodels, usage-statistics

I was trying to translate code from Stata to Python

The original code in Stata:

`reg Y X1 X2 X3 [aw=X4], cluster(X2)`

After a bit of stack-overflowing, I came up with the below lines in Python. But still, I can't manage to get the option [aw=X4]

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
fit = ols("Y ~  X1 +X2 + X3 ", data=df ).fit(cov_type='cluster', cov_kwds={'groups': df['X2']}, use_t=True)
fit.summary()
```

While I know I should use GLS or WLS instead of OLS, and probably insert the argument sigma=xxx somewhere. I have no idea how to do it. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Use `wls` and add the `weights` argument.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's what I was thinking. But where should I insert `weights` argument

Comment: `wls("Y ~  X1 +X2 + X3 ", data=df, weights=df["X4"] )`.

Comment: aside: Statsmodels does not rescale the weights in contrast to Stata. This only effects the estimate of the residual variance `scale`, but not parameters or inference.

Comment: Sorry to ask again: Then what's the method that can also give changes in the estimate in parameters? Is there other way than dividing X4 on the left hand and right-hand side of the regression equation?

Comment: WLS will have different parameter estimates than OLS if weights are not constant. My previous "aside" was about the difference between Stata and statsmodels, not about the difference between WLS and OLS.